# Java: AWT on Solaris

Tags: java, open-source, graphics, solaris, awt

How is AWT implemented for [Solaris](https://www.oracle.com/solaris/solaris11/)?

ie: What native libraries, if any, is it dependent on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Sun JRE: Old school MToolkit use Motify. From 1.5 I think, there is XToolkit which just use xlib. From memory Solaris kept the MToolkit as the default longer than on Linux. It's switchable with the AWT_TOOLKIT environment variable.